# How can I wrap the HTML5 video element's currentTime property?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I'm developing a video player as part of a learning module system. Certain modules require that the user not be able to (easily) skip ahead in the video. I understand that this would normally be considered a bad user experience, but it's essential in this case.

I've been able to override the `video.currentTime` property by doing the following. It prevents skipping, but I need to be able to turn it on and off conditionally.

```
Object.defineProperty(videoElement, 'currentTime', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  get: function() {
    // return from original currentTime
  },
  set: function(newValue) {
    // intercept values here
  }
});
```

how I can reference the original `video.currentTime` property in my getter and setter? Unfortunately, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(videoElement, 'currentTime');` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Why don't you just rename it (e.g. currentTime2) in order to access the original currentTime?

Comment: You can't rename properties, only create new ones and delete old ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but calling the currentTime **getter** of the prototype (in this case the **HTMLMediaElement** prototype) on your object  will give you the actual currentTime. So this will prevent setting but allow getting:

```
  Object.defineProperty(videoElement, 'currentTime', {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      get: function() {
        var ct = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLMediaElement.prototype,
           'currentTime').get.call(this);
        return ct;
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        // intercept values here
      }
    });
```

Comment: Aha! That's perfect. I tried to do something similar to fetch the prototype property but kept getting illegal invocation errors because I was missing `get`.

Comment: Woops, I accidentally assigned the bounty to the wrong person :( I'll start another bounty and give it to you.

Comment: oh! hehe! it was no big deal but ok!

Comment: There we go. Bounty awarded. Everyone has done pretty well off this question, hehe.

Answer (score 1):

If disabling seeking (skipping) is what you want to do then here is my solution:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var supposedCurrentTime = 0;
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  if (!video.seeking) {
        supposedCurrentTime = video.currentTime;
  }
});
// prevent user from seeking
video.addEventListener('seeking', function() {
  // guard agains infinite recursion:
  // user seeks, seeking is fired, currentTime is modified, seeking is fired, current time is modified, ....
  var delta = video.currentTime - supposedCurrentTime;
  if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.01) {
    console.log("Seeking is disabled");
    video.currentTime = supposedCurrentTime;
  }
});
// delete the following event handler if rewind is not required
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  // reset state in order to allow for rewind
    supposedCurrentTime = 0;
});
```

This code simply restores video.currentTime to its last known value when seeking. This effectively cancels the seeking process. There is no need to override/wrap currentTime.

The problem with wrapping currentTime is that if a user is smart enough to select the video element and set its currentTime property then may be the user is smart enough to call:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLMediaElement.prototype,
       'currentTime').set.call(videoElement, videoElement.duration);
```

Comment: I've used this approach before but found it very fragile between browsers since it actually changes the time briefly which can trigger anything watching `timeupdate`.

I'm not worried about people hacking the video. This approach is mostly to prevent accidental clicks or key presses from advancing the video by mistake more than anything. It's just for a learning module that had a legal requirement on the test givers that test takers watch the video all the way through. Users taking the module wouldn't want to skip ahead since they'll miss information they need later.

Comment: Enjoy the accidental 250 bounty points ;) I accidentally awarded them to this question.

Comment: I see, well in that case can't you simply hide the controls? This will effectively eliminate the possibility of misclicking. You may even create your own controls that still have the play/pause and volume buttons but no seek bar. (Thanks for the bounty but now I feel a bit guilty because I don't deserve it.)

Comment: No, they still need to be able to pause, change volume and sometimes fullscreen.